# Use mocked function return value in real function call

Tags: scala, mockito

Is it possible to use a mocked function inside a real function call? Both functions are in the same object. So for example, if I have

```
obj A {
  def mockThis(value: Int): Int = {
    value*5
  }

  def realFuncIWantToTest(value: Int): Int = {
    val v = mockThis(value)
    v
  }
}
```

Obviously this is an extremely simple case and this isn't what my code is doing (v is actually a complicated object). Essentially I want realFuncIWantToTest to use the mocked function return value that I define.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *might* be able to do this using Mockito's spies; see [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-spy-example/) for an example on that.

Spies basically work by having that *spy* wrapping around a *real* object of your class under test.

But one word here: even when it is possible, please consider changing your *design* instead. This "partial mocking" is often a good indication that your class is violating the **single responsibility principle**. Meaning: a class should be responsible for "one" thing. But the idea that you can / have to **partially** mock things within your class indicates that your class is responsible for at least two, somehow disconnect aspects.

In that sense: the **better** approach would be that `mockThis()` would be a call on **another** object; which could be inserted via *dependency injection* into this class.

Long story short: at least on a Java level your idea should work fine (where I have certain doubts that Mockito will work nicely with your *scala* objects) from a technical perspective; but from a conceptual point point; you should rather avoid doing it this way.

Comment: Yep, in the end I decided to change the design and refactored my code. Your suggestion to have `mockThis()` be a call on another object which I inserted with a dependency injection is exactly what I did. Took some time but in the end it made it a lot cleaner and readable too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are very welcome, I am glad you found my suggestion that helpful!